# My Ubuntu 11.10 does not want to shutdown sometimes

Tags: ubuntu, freeze

Sometimes my Ubuntu 11.10 does not want to shutdown properly. After about 3-5 boots, on shutdown it hangs.
I am updating it regularly.

Has anyone encountered this issue?  Could it be because of some updates?
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: see also this AskUbuntu question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72934/shutdown-reboot-occasionally-freezes

Comment: What are the last messages you see on the console? Take a picture with your phone. After reboot, are there hints in /var/log/syslog why the shutdown is hanging?

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem every time I try to shut down. Try `sudo apt-get install -f`. If yours is like mine, that will not work but at least you'll know if you had any broken dependencies. Until a real fix comes around, shut down with `sudo /sbin/poweroff now`.